# I need method which take String as input and return ebcdic representaion of String as byte[]

Tags: java, ebcdic

```
public byte[] stringToEbcdic(String s, String encoding){

    String payload = null;
    try {
        payload = new String(s.getBytes("encoding"), "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return payload.getBytes();
}
```

I should be able to call the method like

```
byte[] b = stringToEbcdic("abcd", "IBM01140");
```

but its not working.

Comment: Not working as in exception/wrong result/computer crashed/...?

Answer (score 0):

```
payload = new String(s.getBytes("encoding"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

should be

```
// encoding is a variable, not a string literal
payload = new String(s.getBytes(encoding), "ISO-8859-1");
```

However, you're doing some strange further manipulation of the string. The whole method could be simplified to the working version;

```
public static byte[] stringToEbcdic(String s, String encoding) {
    try {
        return s.getBytes(encoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```